# Login Form, If Connected or Not-Connected

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I'm using the login form of this website http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html, And i would like to display:

```
If you are connected, display Welcome ["name"]
Else if you are not, display Sign Up, Login.
```

I tried different ways, but it doesn't work. Could you help me please.
Thank you a lot, regards.

Comment: Use this if you use the same login form as me:                            `if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) { $loggedin="0";} else { $loggedin="1"; } if ($loggedin=="0"){ echo '<a href="register.php?new=1">Sign Up</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a>'; } else if ($loggedin=="1") { echo "<a href='account.php'>Welcome, "; echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); echo "</a>"; }`

Comment: That tutorial is *dangerous*.  It wraps the *deprecated* `mysql_` functions in a silly pseudo-OO library, it uses unsalted MD5 to hash passwords and generally ignores or glosses over every possible applicable security-related question that could be raised.  I recommend avoiding that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition with Mr.Alien answer, Use [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) function to do this.

Put a `user_id` in session, show welcome message if session been set, show Sign up | Login if session not been set.

```
$_SESSION['user_id']; 

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

  echo 'Welcome <username>';
}else{
  echo 'Sign Up';
}
```

Comment: Thank You alot LearneR, I've found it, the reply is on Mr.Alien Post. Thank you a lot you two!

Comment: It's my pleasure Samuel and Welcome to SO :-)